# iOS UIActionsheet and flickr sdk conflict

Tags: ios, flickr

We are using flickr ios sdk in order get photos. And app should start to download 
images when user clicks to uiactionsheet item. After clicking item the current controller pops from navigation stack. And after that the app crashes and I see only  [LFHTTPRequest(PrivateMethods) readStreamHasBytesAvailable] message.
When we use some view instead of actions sheet all work very well. 
I read that this is a flickr's bug but I haven't found any solution for this.

Comment: I think you need to post the associated code. As a guess, the LFHTTPRequest instance got released, but without the code I can't be sure.